# Illegal unit of measurement error when typesetting chapter mark

Tags: xetex

I have a class file like this

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tjutest}[2015/01/12 test commands]
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}

\newcommand*\MakePerPage[2][\@ne]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname c@pchk@#2\endcsname{\c@pchk@{#2}{#1}}%
    \newcounter{pcabs@#2}%
    \@addtoreset{pchk@#2}{#2}}
  \def\new@pagectr#1{\@newl@bel{pchk@#1}}
  \def\c@pchk@#1#2{\z@=\z@
    \begingroup
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\next\csname pchk@#1@\arabic{pcabs@#1}\endcsname
    \addtocounter{pcabs@#1}\@ne
    \expandafter\ifx\csname pchk@#1@\arabic{pcabs@#1}\endcsname\next
    \else \setcounter{#1}{#2}\fi
    \protected@edef\next{%
      \string\new@pagectr{#1}{\arabic{pcabs@#1}}{\noexpand\thepage}}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\next}%
  \endgroup\global\z@}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
```

You can make the tex file like this.

```
\documentclass{tjutest}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\chapter{The first}
\section{the first}
see if error exists
\end{document}
```

Then I got the error message like this.Can somebody help me?

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
                   \global
l.6 \chapter{The first}

? x
```

If you don't mind, can you write down the process or way of you thinking about the problem not just the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I guess from the name (but I'd never guess from the code) that the intention is to have per-page footnotes in which case I suggest you remove it all and just have

```
\RequirePackage[perpage]{footmisc}
```

Comment: Thanks, and it works. I also find there exist a perpage package, is there any difference between these two packages? which is better?

Comment: @Svandex both have long history and probably work, the code you showed looks like it has been originally copied from the `perpage`  package but incompletely/incorrectly (I did start to debug it but just using a package that has working code seemed like a better suggestion:-) they have overlapping aims `perpage` is a general mechanism for page counters and footnotes is just an example, `footmisc` is a general package of footnote features of which resetting per page  is just an example. So you are at the intersection....